# API design / Command pattern vs. "normal implementation"

Tags: java, api, design-patterns

I'm working on a tree-structured storage and we currently use transaction methods to modify the tree-structure. I always thought using the Command Pattern would be appropriate. However I just changed a small behaviour and I like it (returning the transaction instance located at the inserted node (except for attributes)):

```
wtx.insertText(EInsert.ASRIGHTSIBLING, "value").insertElement(EInsert.ASRIGHTSIBLING, new QName("bla").insertElement(EInsert.ASFIRSTCHILD, new QName("blubb")).insertAttribute(new QName("foo"), "bar").insertAttribute(new QName("bar"), "foo"));
```

I think chaining the operations this way is very nice, but our transactions provide cursor like methods on the tree (`moveTo(long)`, `moveToParent()`, `moveToFirstChild()`...) which return boolean values instead of the current transaction instance, but I think this can't be avoided. Otherwise we could even do moves between without the cumbersome

```
wtx.method();wtx.method();wtx.method();
```

However I thought about the command pattern which would be

```
new InsertText(EInsert.ASRIGHTSIBLING, "value").execute(wtx);
new InsertElement(EInsert.ASRIGHTSIBLING, new QName("bla")).execute(wtx);
...
```

which is a bit more verbose but well, it would "support" the open/closed principle which is really nice.

So, what do you think?

Answer (score 1):

The tree structure to me sounds like it can be described like a giant composite object.  Since you're also dealing with building a transaction I think using the Command pattern would be appropriate but you should consider wrapping your execute() calls in some kind of director if possible such that you kind of mash the Command and Builder patterns together if possible.

```
public void directorMethod(Object wtx) {
  InsertText(EInsert.ASRIGHTSIBLING, "value").execute(wtx);
  InsertText(EInsert.ASRIGHTSIBLING, "blah").execute(wtx);
}
```

Note, the void return could be your tree structure and the wtx parameter can be the transaction and/or tree structure, I'm not necessarily sure how you would want to do it.  The idea of using the Builder would be to abstract the building of the Composite transaction from the underlying implementation.  That way if you need to change an underlying command, you should be able to do so and test atomically.

Comment: What do you mean with "The idea of using the Builder would be to abstract the building of the Composite transaction from the underlying implementation."? The tree-structure itself is a giant composite object (with "pointers"). I'm not sure if it's worth the effort. We have used the methods internally so often, and I would have to rewrite a bunch of code. But luckily we do not have any external users as of now ;-) So I can change virtually anything and I want to provide a clean nice API.

Comment: BTW: Normally you'd use some sort of import (from XML-documents for instance) and then do some changes with the Java API or maybe someday with XQuery Update or something like that.

Comment: @Johannes - Composites are generally built using Builders.  So as long as the tree structure is viewed as a composite object rather than as a document or single datasource, it's worth considering.  The idea is to abstract the construction to a director so that you're guaranteed proper creation.

Comment: I don't really know, but I think then it's more a document or single datasource. For instance one can import an XML-document into a database which would be a single resource in the database. Furthermore we store snapshots (after commiting transactions). So you open a specific revision of the resource (the tree-structure) and you can manipulate and persist the changes. But every kind of tree-structure is possible, besides a few constraints for sure (ElementNode cannot be a child of a TextNode...). Ah you are referring to the composite pattern. But no, our nodes have to be unique (unique ID).

Comment: Even then, I would still try to find an abstraction where you can replicate process.  The more reuse you can make, the better.